# My neural network has a very bad accuracy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import functools

COLUMNS = ["Alter", "Gender", "BMI", "Fever", "Nausea", "Fatigue",
                  "WBC", "RBC", "HGB", "Plat", "AST1", "ALT1", "ALT4", "ALT12", "ALT24", "ALT36", "ALT48", "ALT24w",
                  "RNABase", "RNA4", "Baseline", "Endstage"]

feature_name = COLUMNS[:-1]
LABEL_NAME = 'Endstage'

batch_size = 32

def get_dataset(file_path, **kwargs):
    train_dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_path,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        label_name = LABEL_NAME,
        ignore_errors=True,
        num_epochs=5,
        **kwargs
    )
    return train_dataset

train_data = get_dataset("HCVnew.csv")


def show_batch(dataset):
  for batch, label in dataset.take(1):
    for key, value in batch.items():
      print("{:20s}: {}".format(key,value.numpy()))



SELECT_COLUMNS = ["Alter", "Gender", "BMI", "Fever", "Nausea", "Fatigue",
                  "WBC", "RBC", "HGB", "Plat", "AST1", "ALT1", "ALT4", "ALT12", "ALT24", "ALT36", "ALT48", "ALT24w",
                  "RNABase", "RNA4", "Baseline", "Endstage"]

DEFAULTS = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

uni_data = get_dataset("HCVnew.csv", select_columns = SELECT_COLUMNS, column_defaults = DEFAULTS)



def pack(features, label):
  return tf.stack(list(features.values()), axis=-1), label

packed_dataset = uni_data.map(pack)
"""
for features, labels in packed_dataset.take(1):
  print(features.numpy())
  print()
  print(labels.numpy())
"""


class PackNumericFeatures(object):
  def __init__(self, names):
    self.names = names

  def __call__(self, features, labels):
    numeric_features = [features.pop(name) for name in self.names]
    numeric_features = [tf.cast(feat, tf.float32) for feat in numeric_features]
    numeric_features = tf.stack(numeric_features, axis=-1)
    features['numeric'] = numeric_features

    return features, labels

NUMERIC_FEATURES = ["Alter", "Gender", "BMI", "Fever", "Nausea", "Fatigue",
                  "WBC", "RBC", "HGB", "Plat", "AST1", "ALT1", "ALT4", "ALT12", "ALT24", "ALT36", "ALT48", "ALT24w",
                  "RNABase", "RNA4", "Baseline"]

packed_train_data = train_data.map(
    PackNumericFeatures(NUMERIC_FEATURES))

#show_batch(packed_train_data)

desc = pd.read_csv("HCVnew.csv")[NUMERIC_FEATURES].describe()
desc

MEAN = np.array(desc.T['mean'])
STD = np.array(desc.T['std'])

def normalize_numeric_data(data, mean, std):
  # Center the data
  return (data-mean)/std

normalizer = functools.partial(normalize_numeric_data, mean=MEAN, std=STD)

numeric_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('numeric', normalizer_fn=normalizer, shape=[len(NUMERIC_FEATURES)])
numeric_columns = [numeric_column]

numeric_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(numeric_columns)

#preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(numeric_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  numeric_layer,
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

train_data = packed_train_data.shuffle(500)

model.fit(train_data, epochs=20)
```

My neural network has an accuracy of 25%, what is very bad. My training data contains 1200 samples but just after one or two epochs the accuracy remains 25% and I have tried to change batch size and amount of epochs but nothing works. The number of labels is 4 (1, 2, 3, 4).
If someone has an idea what I could improve then please tell me.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It is not python, nor numpy or tensorflow related thing. Your features may not characterize well your data, or the selected algorithm is not suitable for the problem. Also, you may need to adjust the parameters of your selected algorith. This is absolutely not python-related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The number of labels is 4 (1, 2, 3, 4)

If you have 4 labels, then this is not a binary problem and therefore you need to adapt your network to a multi-label classification :

- One hot encode your labels
- Use a last Dense layer with NB_CLASS neurones (4 in your case) and a Softmax activation
- Use categorical_crossentropy as loss

If you use a Dense layer like that :

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

It will have the default parameters, and in this case have a linear activation which is not what you want in a binary OR multi-label classification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response! Since, as you can clearly see, I'm quite new to neural networks comments like yours are liquid gold for me! If you know any good platform where exactly things like this are explained, please tell me. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to have helped you ! You can start with this link : http://cs231n.github.io/. 
This course is "liquid gold" as you say ;)